# PYTHON - QUrl.fromLocalFile("testurl.html") - не находит файл

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui

Всем привет. Эксперименты продолжаются, а я все тот же чайник.
В общем суть - нарисовал я интерфейс, научил его показывать вебстраницы из интернета, все хорошо. Но теперь задача - подгрузить вместо вебстраницы (url) - локальный файл.

Торжественно клянусь что замышляю только шалость)

Возможно надо просто добавить путь, но когда я попытался это сделать код поломался)

код:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QLabel, QLineEdit,
    QTextEdit, QGridLayout, QApplication,QPushButton)
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets,QtGui,QtCore
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets,QtGui,QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *




class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):

        title = QLabel('Ссылка на сайт или файл')
        author = QLabel('Строка ввода')
        output = QLabel('Поле вывода')
        buttontop = QPushButton("Go!")
        buttondown = QPushButton("Add!")
        titleEdit = QLineEdit('Ссылка на сайт или файл')
        authorEdit = QLineEdit()
        outputEdit = QTextEdit()
        outputEdit.setReadOnly(True)

        grid = QGridLayout()
        grid.setSpacing(12)

        grid.addWidget(title, 1, 0)         
        grid.addWidget(titleEdit, 1, 1)
        grid.addWidget(buttontop, 1,2)
        w=QWebEngineView()
        
        w.load(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile("testurl.html")) ## В этой строчке нужно открыть локальный файл testurl.html
        
        
        grid.addWidget(output, 2, 0)
        grid.addWidget(w, 2, 1, 4, 2)

        grid.addWidget(author, 6, 0)
        grid.addWidget(authorEdit, 6, 1)
        grid.addWidget(buttondown, 6,2)

        

        self.setLayout(grid)

        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 1420, 680)
        self.setWindowTitle('Review')
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #app=QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    
    
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

вылечилось вот так:

w.load(QtCore.QUrl('file:///C:/testurl.html'))